# Why new Azure Storage Client Library 2.0 has poor query performance compare to legacy TableServiceQuery?

Tags: performance, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I just do the proof of concept to measure performance improvement for new Azure Storage Client Library 2.0 and its legacy TableServiceQuery.

After run the result, I'm surprise! Instead of Azure SCL 2.0 will have performance gain. Its performance is poor by double compare to TableServiceQuery.

Here is my code:

```
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigHelper.DataConnectionString);
var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
var context = tableClient.GetTableServiceContext();
var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("User");

var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var query = context.CreateQuery<User>("User");
    var temp = (from item in query
                where item.PartitionKey == "12345"
                select item).First();
    temp.ToString();
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("TableServiceQuery: " + sw.Elapsed);

sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var query = new TableQuery<User>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "12345")).Take(1);
    var temp = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented(query, null).First();
    temp.ToString();
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("TableQuery: " + sw.Elapsed);
```

And result is

```
TableServiceQuery: 00:00:13.8179295
TableQuery: 00:00:34.8782858
```

I tried several times but new SCL 2.0 (TableQuery) always spent time more than double. The table 'User' which I query have records around million records.

My understand is new API should have major performance improvement. Anybody please explain did I am missing something in my code? Or what should I do to make new library has better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved in SDK 2.0.6.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this test on a Windows Azure role, please make sure you disable Intellitrace when deploying. More information on Intellitrace for cloud services can be found in the [Debugging a Published Cloud Service with IntelliTrace and Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683671.aspx) article.

Comment: I haven't enable intellitrace.